Como cambiar el nombre del SEQUENCE que esta en la KB y que se genera del AUTONUMBER de un atributo?
Cuando se crea un atributo con la propiedad AUTONUMBER=true, genexus crea un objeto SEQUENCE en la KB y en la base de datos (Ejemplo Oracle) con el nombre del atributo. Por ejemplo:

Nombre de Atributo en KB: PersonaId
Nombre de Sequence en KB: PersonaId
Nombre de Sequence en Oracle: PersonaId

Nota: Además, genexus crea el trigger en la base de datos que se encarga de actualizar el Id con el sequence. Este objeto no es relevante en este caso.
El modelo de base de datos (oracle) de la empresa en la que laboro contiene estándares de nomenclatura que NO permiten la creación de un objeto sequence con el nombre "PersonaId". En su lugar se debe crear el sequence con el nombre "SEQ_Persona_Id"
Genexus, internamente, usa ese nombre de sequence (PersonaId) para actualizar las key's de los sub-niveles de la transacción.
Para ello, genexus, en sus programas fuentes (extension .cs) ejecuta lo siguiente: PersonaId.CURRVAL y como NO EXISTE en la base de datos oracle, genexus, devuelve siempre el valor CERO y por lo tanto pierden relación con las transacciones de sub-niveles.
Esto se corregiría si pudiera cambiar el nombre del sequence en la KB por el correcto  SEQ_Persona_Id.CURRVAL , así genexus devolvería el valor correcto y las transacciones de sub-niveles estarían relacionadas.
He revisado los DATA VIEW y no hay referencia a los nombres de sequences.
Es por ello que necesito renombrar el SEQUENCE (PersonaId) de la KB que utiliza genexus por el que existe en la base de datos oracle.
Me podrían indicar como hacerlo o me puedan dar algún tipo de guía ?
Gracias
